# How to test Either from bloctest

Tags: flutter, flutter-mockito

I use this library [fpdart](https://pub.dev/packages/fpdart) with [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) for State Management. From fpDart I'm just using `Either` to manage errors.
But now, when I'm doing my unit test for the Bloc I call a funcion that looks like this

`Future<Either<Failure, List<Anime>>> getPopularAnime();`

When I run this test:

```
group('⭐️ When [Started] is added.  ', () {
    Failure failure = Failure.badRequest();
    final failureEither = Either<Failure, List<Anime>>.left(failure);

    blocTest('emits [Loading,Error]',
        build: () => landingBloc,
        setUp: () {
          when(animeRepository.getPopularAnime())
              .thenAnswer((_) async => failureEither);
        },
        act: (bloc) => bloc.add(const LandingEvent.started()),
        expect: () => [
              const LandingState.loading(),
              LandingState.error(failure),
            ]);
  });
```

The `animeRepository` that is in the code is a Mock generated by `@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<AnimeRepository>()])`

[Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) says this

> MissingDummyValueError: Either<Failure, List<Anime>> This means
> Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type
> 'Either<Failure, List<Anime>>'. Please consider using either
> 'provideDummy' or 'provideDummyBuilder' functions to give Mockito a
> proper dummy value.

I expect when the bloc calls animeRepository.getPopularAnime() it returns Either<Failure, List<Anime>> because the bloc emits error in case of Left or emits success in case of right.

Comment: You should see the way fpdart tests itself, and write similar tests.  The self-tests are quite comprehensive.

Comment: Do you have any news on this, I got the exact same problem when I updated fpdart from 0.4.x to 1.1.x

Comment: Same problem for me. Any update about this?